# How to load Google SDK in Cakephp 3.9

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I have to load a Google plugin into the Cakephp 3.9 Application and need to be used inside the controller.

Google plugin places inside the Vendor folder
vendor/Google

Anyone can help for below points

- How to load Plugin
- How to import into the controller

I have used below link for reference:
https://api.cakephp.org/3.9/class-Cake.Core.Plugin.html

Comment: There are different SDKs for different Google products, however none of those SDKs are CakePHP "Plugins". The term "Plugin" has a very specific meaning in the context of the CakePHP framework, please clarify what exactly you are talking about, the Google SDK (and which SDK specifically), or a CakePHP plugin (and if so, which plugin)!? Furthermore please explain what exactly you want to "_import into the controller_"!?

Comment: I want to use `Google_Client` & `Google_Service_Drive` services.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What's the problem in simply installing whatever you want to install using Composer?

Comment: @NicoHaase, I have an installed Google SDK using composer, but unable to import into the controller...., I have to use Google_Client & Google_Service_Drive services.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Any code you could share? Something like an error message?

Answer (score 1):

I use `Google_Client` in CakePHP - you shouldn't have to do anything special to use it. If it's installed via composer it's already in Composer's autoloader, you can call it directly.

Ex. In `composer.json` after running `./composer.phar require google/apiclient:"^2.7"` My require section lists the Google API:

```
"require": {
    "google/apiclient": "^2.7",
```

Make sure you run `./composer.phar install` if it wasn't already installed durring `require`.

Then in to use the library, I just call it directly, prefixed with `\` since it's not namespaced:

```
public function index()
{
    $client = new \Google_Client();
```

If you're curious how this works under the hood - Composer will generate all the information it needs to load classes durring `require` or `install` and sticks these in several files back in `vendor/composer`, such as `autoload_namespaces.php`, where it should automatically have added `Google_` to the list there, ex:

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    // Lots of class prefixes, but eventually:
    'Google_' => array($vendorDir . '/google/apiclient/src'),
```

Classes that are namespaced to industry standards like PSR-4 (like all modern PHP libs probably should be!) are probably in `autoloader_psr4.php` - and so on. It registers it's own autoloader in ClassLoader.php, and sticks a reference to this in `vendor/autoload.php` - which Cake calls essentially on near line 1 of
`webroot/index.php`:

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

So in short - you don't need to worry about autoloading again so long as you're working through Composer.

Also - if you're able to use an IDE which helps with autocompletion of class namespaces, like PHPStorm, that might make things easier.

Answer (score -3):

For libraries that specify autoload information, Composer generates a vendor/autoload.php file. You can simply include this file and start using the classes that those libraries provide without any extra work:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

For more references : https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: Please share some explanation - this single line of code does not help a lot